# Gradle: Multi-Project Build with project dependent property

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-multi-project-build

I'm currently trying to create a multi project build with gradle which should produce multiple ear files. All ear files are using a shared ejb project which bundles an ejb-jar.xml deployment descriptor. This deployment descriptor should contain an env-entry which is dependent on the ear-project.

Here is how the project structure looks like:

```
├───ear-project1
│       build.gradle
├───ear-project2
│       build.gradle
├───ejb-project
│   │   build.gradle
│   └───src
│       └───main
│           └───resources
│               └───META-INF
│                       ejb-jar.xml
├───build.gradle
```

**build.gradle (root)**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
}
```

**build.gradle (ear)**

```
apply plugin: 'ear'

dependencies {
    deploy project(':ejb-project')
}
```

**build.gradle (ejb)**

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens

ext {
    placeholder = 'thisShouldBeSetByTheEar'
}

processResources {
    with copySpec {
        from 'src/main/resources'
        filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [replaceMe: placeholder])
    }
}
```

The whole project should be created by one single command, e.g. `gradle ear`.

So far I've tried to inject the property via a closure, but it does not seem to work:

```
deploy project(':ejb-project', { placeholder = 'ear-project1' })
```

How can I configure the ear projects to set the `placeholder` variable of the ejb project?

You can access the complete example via GitHub: https://github.com/monsieurvader/multiproject-ear

Comment: What exactly is the question? Please state the problem clearly.

Comment: Added a question at the end which should hopefully clarify the problem.